# Checksum - CRC Bluetooth - Flutter (FlutterBlue)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-bluetooth

I am using Flutter Blue by connecting with a reloj. According to the API of the manufacturer of that reloj, to change the date and it is as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCdH9.png)

When I put this code, I call 0x01 to send data to it, but in turn we see that it responds as a success.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6q8U.png)

The problem is that when I try to send them the data, for example, today's date, I get the following error, which is 0x81

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsDC1.png)

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? it would be a great help, thanks.

Comment: The data may be sending well, but the error would be with the checksum, does anyone know of a way to get it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Returning to the previous example, we have the following byte array.

```
[0x01 0x21 0x12 0x07 0x11 0x02 0x23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ??]
```

As we can see, our array is 15 bytes, but how do we get the checksum that would be the final position to complete the 16 bytes needed in the array?

We will convert each position of the array from hexadecimal to decimal:

```
0x01 0x21 0x12 0x07 0x11 0x02 0x23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 => Hex
01    33   18   07   17   02   35  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 => Decimal
```

Once we have the decimals, we add them.

```
01 + 33 + 18 + 07 + 17 + 02 + 35 = 96
```

For the given example, we could say that our Checksum is 96:

```
[0x01 0x21 0x12 0x07 0x11 0x02 0x23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 96]
```

I hope I have helped future programmers with my answer.